# Qt C++ QTcp как определить что приходит клиенту сообщение или картинка

Tags: c++, qt, сокет

Разбираюсь с Tcp протоколом в Qt. Есть сервер он передаёт сообщение клиенту.

```
void Server::sendToClientMessage()
{
if (socket != NULL)
{
    // Заранее размер блока неизвестен, мы не можем записать данные сразу в сокет,
    // так как размер блока должен быть выслан в первую очередь
    QByteArray  arrBlock;
    QDataStream out(&arrBlock, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);
    // Записываем все данные блока, размер 0
    out << quint16(0);
    out << QTime::currentTime() << ui->lineEdit_message->text();
    // Вывод вашего сообщения в историю сообщений
    ui->textEdit_allMessage->append(QTime::currentTime().toString() + " - Ваше сообщение: " + ui->lineEdit_message->text());
    // Перемещение указателя на начало блока
    out.device()->seek(0);
    // Вычисление размера блока arrSize уменьшенный на sizeof(quint16)
    // запись в поток out с текущей позиции, которая уже перемещена в начало блока
    out << quint16(arrBlock.size() - sizeof(quint16));

    // Созданный блок записывается в сокет
    socket->write(arrBlock);
    ui->lineEdit_message->clear();
}
else
{
    return;
}
}
```

Он же отправляет картинку клиенту по кнопке pushButton

```
void Server::transferImage()
{
QBuffer buffer;
QImageWriter writer(&buffer, "jpg");
writer.write(imageJPEG);

QByteArray barr;
QDataStream stream(&barr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);
stream << (quint32)buffer.size();
barr.append(buffer.data());

socket->write(barr);
}
```

Как на стороне клиента определить, что приходит? сообщение или картинка? 
Тут есть 2 коннекта

```
// Передача сообщения клиенту
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
// Передача картинки клиенту
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(receivingImage()));
```

Сейчас отрабатывают 2 метода и это не правильно. Если мы передаем картинку он пытается отобразить и сообщение тоже, хотя мы его не передавали и наоборот. Из за этого ни один из методов не работает. Если же закомментировать один из коннектов и соответствующий слот то всё норм. Т.е либо сообщение либо картинка. Можно было бы запихнуть в один метод и внутри уже разбирать, но как внутри метода определять картинка там или только сообщение?

Метод подключения к серверу

```
void Client::connectedToServer()
{
// Если клиент уже подключен
if(socket != NULL)
{
    // Отключить клиента клиента
    disconnectFromServer();
}
else
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    // Подключение к серверу
    socket->connectToHost(ui->lineEdit_ipAddress->text(),ui->spinBox_port->value());

    // оповестить пользователя что он подключён
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(slotConnected()));
    //connect(sock)
    // Возможные ошибки при подключении
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(slotError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

    // Передача сообщения клиенту
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
    // Передача картинки клиенту
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(receivingImage()));

}
}
```

Получение сообщения

```
void Client::slotReadyRead()
{
// Считывание в двоичный поток данных, объект класса socket унасследованный от QIODevice
QDataStream in(socket);

// Так как формат постоянно изменяется,  и в разных версиях он может работать по разному.
// Установка формата обмена данных на версию Qt 5.7.
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);

// Не все высланные клиентом данные могут прийти одновременно.
// Сервер должен уметь получать, как весь блок целиком, так и только часть блока,
// а так же и все блоки сразу.
for (;;)
{
    // Размер блока заранее неизвестен, сравниваем с нулём.
    if (nextBlockSize == 0)
    {
        // Если пришло меньше 2-х байт, ждём пока будет 2 байта.
        // Первые 2 байта это размер блока
        if (socket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint16))
        {
            break;
        }
        // Блок получен целиком. Считываем размер блока (2 байта)
        in >> nextBlockSize;
    }
    // Ждём пока блок придёт полностью
    if (socket->bytesAvailable() < nextBlockSize)
    {
        break;
    }

    // Вот тут можно было бы определять картинка здесь или сообщение, но как?


    // Определяем дату и строку, они в сообщении сервера
    QTime   time;
    QString str;
    // Считывание данных из потока в переменные
    in >> time >> str;

    ui->textEdit_allMessage->append(time.toString() + " - Сообщение от сервера: " + str);

    // Каждый раз обнуляем блок, для принятия следующего
    nextBlockSize = 0;
}
}
```

Получение картинки

```
void Client::receivingImage()
{
if (nextBlockSize == 0)
{
    QDataStream stream(socket);

    if (socket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint32))
        return;

    stream >> nextBlockSize;
}

if (nextBlockSize > socket->bytesAvailable())
    return;

QByteArray barr = socket->read(nextBlockSize);
QBuffer buffer(&barr);
buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QImageReader reader(&buffer, "jpg");
receivingImageJPG = reader.read();

if (!receivingImageJPG.isNull())
{
    ui->label_reciveImageJPG->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(receivingImageJPG).scaled(ui->label_reciveImageJPG->size(),
                                                                                     Qt::KeepAspectRatio,
                                                                                     Qt::SmoothTransformation));

    nextBlockSize = 0;
}
else
{
    ui->label_reciveImageJPG->setText("Возникла ошибка при передачи картинки.");
}
}
```

Вот что то типо такого нужно. Но тут жесткое ограничение если приходит более 10 килобайт считаем, что это картинка и отображаем. Если меньше, то сообщение. Как заранее распознать что хранится в QDataStream сообщение или картинка?

```
void Client::slotReadyRead()
{
// Считывание в двоичный поток данных, объект класса socket унасследованный от QIODevice
QDataStream in(socket);

// Так как формат постоянно изменяется,  и в разных версиях он может работать по разному.
// Установка формата обмена данных на версию Qt 5.7.
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);

// Не все высланные клиентом данные могут прийти одновременно.
// Сервер должен уметь получать, как весь блок целиком, так и только часть блока,
// а так же и все блоки сразу.
for (;;)
{
    // Размер блока заранее неизвестен, сравниваем с нулём.
    if (nextBlockSize == 0)
    {
        // Если пришло меньше 2-х байт, ждём пока будет 2 байта.
        // Первые 2 байта это размер блока
        if (socket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(quint64))
        {
            break;
        }
        // Блок получен целиком. Считываем размер блока (2 байта)
        in >> nextBlockSize;
    }
    // Ждём пока блок придёт полностью
    if (socket->bytesAvailable() < nextBlockSize)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (nextBlockSize < 10000)
    {
        // Определяем дату и строку, они в сообщении сервера
        QTime   time;
        QString str;
        // Считывание данных из потока в переменные
        in >> time >> str;

        ui->textEdit_allMessage->append(time.toString() + " - Сообщение от сервера: " + str);
    }
    else
    {

        QByteArray barr = socket->read(nextBlockSize);
        QBuffer buffer(&barr);
        buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        QImageReader reader(&buffer, "jpg");
        receivingImageJPG = reader.read();

        if (!receivingImageJPG.isNull())
        {
            ui->label_reciveImageJPG->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(receivingImageJPG).scaled(ui->label_reciveImageJPG->size(),
                                                                                             Qt::KeepAspectRatio,
                                                                                             Qt::SmoothTransformation));

        }
        else
        {
            ui->label_reciveImageJPG->setText("Возникла ошибка при передачи картинки.");
        }
    }

    // Каждый раз обнуляем блок, для принятия следующего
    nextBlockSize = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: А если предварять некоторым кодом, что именно идет дальше?

Comment: Не очень знаком с QTcp, но как вариант в начале можно отправлять дополнительное сообщение, где будет информация о типе передаваемых данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если между передающей и принимающей стороной нет какого-либо соглашения о характере содержимого на текущую сессию, то можно отправлять все возможные варианты сразу. Это как коробка конфет. Она может быть полной, а может быть частично дегустирована. Вроде все формальности соблюдены: коробка, ленточка с бантиком. Но не оставляет чувство жёсткого... недоумения при непосредственном изучении содержимого.

Объявление класса подарка:

```
class Gift {
    friend QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Gift &gift);
    friend QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &stream, Gift &gift);

    public:
        Gift() {}
        virtual ~Gift() {}

        QString text() const {return _txt}
        void setText(const QString &txt) {_txt = txt;}

        QImage image() const {return _img;}
        void setImage(const QImage &img) {_img = img;}

    private:
        QString _txt;
        QImage  _img;

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Gift)
```

Где-нибудь в реализации класса подарка:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Gift>("Gift");
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<Gift>("Gift");

QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &stream, const Gift &gift) {
    return stream << gift._txt << gift._img;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &stream, Gift &gift) {
    stream >> gift._txt >> gift._img;
    return stream;
}
```

Далее, остаётся лишь оформить, собственно, передачу (`_socket` - объект класса наследника `QAbstractSocket`):

```
QByteArray SocketManager::compressData(const QVariant &var) {
    QByteArray data;

    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);
    stream << var;

    return qCompress(data, 9);
}

QVariant SocketManager::uncompressData(const QByteArray &data) {
    QByteArray raw_data = qUncompress(data);
    if(raw_data.isEmpty()) return QVariant();

    QDataStream stream(raw_data);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);

    QVariant var;
    stream >> var;

    return var;
}

void SocketManager::sendMessage(const QVariant &var) {
    QByteArray data;

    QDataStream stream(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);
    stream << compressData(var);

    // Вставлять в поток размер блока данных необходимости нет
    // в том случае, если используется Qt 5.7 и выше.

    _socket->write(data);
}

void SocketManager::onReadyRead() {
    QDataStream stream(_socket);
    stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_DefaultCompiledVersion);

    while(_socket->bytesAvailable()) {
        stream.startTransaction();

        QByteArray data;
        stream >> data;

        // Собственно проверка данных принятого размера
        // для Qt 5.7 и выше.
        if(stream.commitTransaction() == false) return;

        QVariant var = uncompressData(data);

        if(var.isValid() && var.canConvert<Gift>()) {
            // Время открывать шампанское.
            Gift gift = var.value<Gift>();
        }
    }
}
```

Объект класса подарка можно наполнить всеми типами данных, можно частично, а можно и вообще не заполнять, оставив пустым, так сказать, для большей радости юбиляра:

```
Gift gift;
gift.setText("Безвозмездно");
gift.setImage(QImage(":/gift.jpg"));
```

А отправлять можно так:

```
manager->sendMessage(QVariant::fromValue<Gift>(gift));
```

Answer (score 2):

Словом, безотносительно к конкретно Qt... При передаче по сети - примерно как с безымянным файлом: есть просто поток данных. Как вы узнаете, что именно в нем - JPEG или "Война и мир"? :) Например, по начальным байтам ("заголовку") файла.

Так и здесь - используйте свой протокол. Самое простое - пересылайте перед отправлением информации информацию о том, что сейчас будет идти. Как в старой комедии - "Возьми трубку, я буду говорить с тобой по телефону!"

Можете даже предварять информацией не только о типе, но и, например, о размере передаваемых данных или еще чем-то - тут уж как ваша фантазия и ваши потребности скажут.

Получив заголовок, вы будете точно знать, что получаете дальше.